# writing a parser in prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg

Here is the grammar:

```
<S>-><X><Y><Z>
<X>->a<X>|a
<Y>->b<Y>|b
<Z>->c<Z>|c
```

I need to write a parser in this grammar.

and when test S([a,a,b,c,c,c],[]).
it should return true.
in my code I defined match rule to check list elements.

```
match(H,[H|T],T).
na(X0,X1):-match(a,X0,X2). 
nb(X0,X1):-match(b,X0,X2). 
nc(X0,X1):-match(c,X0,X2).
ns(X0,X1):-na(X0,X2),nb(X2,X3),nc(X3,X1).
```

what is wrong in this code? it give true but when you trace. it does not working.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how this site works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

s --> x, y, z.
x --> "a",x|"a".
y --> "b",y|"b".
z --> "c",z|"c".
```

Here they are, sorted by length:

```
?- length(Xs,N),phrase(s, Xs).
   Xs = [a,b,c], N = 3
;  Xs = [a,a,b,c], N = 4
;  Xs = [a,b,b,c], N = 4
;  Xs = [a,b,c,c], N = 4
;  Xs = [a,a,a,b,c], N = 5
;  Xs = [a,a,b,b,c], N = 5
;  ... .
```

Comment: could you explain me how this is going to help me.am I going to define a rule for set_prolog_flag?

Comment: @user127518: simply copy-paste the text into a file, and then consult it `[file].`

Comment: I understood it now, yep it is working. I was not it to be that short and simple